# Read from file c++ always can't read

Tags: c++, fstream, readfile, ifstream

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("FileTest");

string line;

if(myfile.is_open())
{
  cout<<"Reading from file...";
  getline(myfile,line);
}

if(myfile.fail())
{
    cout<<"Unable to open file"<<endl;
}

myfile.close();
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. (And post a [mcve].)

Comment: Use the full path of file `FileTest`, e.g. `"c:\\myTestData\\FileTest"` (Note the double backslashes in the string literal (each double backslash in the string literal denotes a single backslach in the string's content then).

Comment: I found the proble I forgot to put .txt after the file name

Comment: @StephanLechner because I am working in the same directory/folder I can put just the name. But you are right it is safer to put the full path especially when the file is on another directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ tries to open the file in the current directory with the exact name `FileTest`. Check to see if the file is in the current directory? Maybe you spelled the name incorrectly? Maybe you forgot to write `FileTest.txt`? You are using `ifstream`, which will fail if the file you're trying to open does not exist or is corrupted.